# The mysterious fractions

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

Let's have the following fractions.

$ \frac{752}{375} + \frac{754}{376}+ \frac{756}{377} + \frac{758}{378}+ \frac{760}{379} \approx 10\times(\frac{5}{375}+1)^{1/5}$

$\frac{752}{375}+ \frac{754}{376}+ \frac{756}{377}+ \frac{758}{378}+ \frac{760}{379}+ \frac{762}{380} \approx 12\times(\frac{6}{375}+1)^{1/6}$

$\frac{752}{375}+ \frac{754}{376}+\frac{756}{377}+ \frac{758}{378}+ \frac{760}{379}+ \frac{762}{380}+ \frac{764}{381} \approx 14\times(\frac{7}{375}+1)^{1/7}$

What is the explanation for these almost equalities?

<sub>Transcription of math: 752/375 + 754/376 + 756/377 + 758/378 + 760/379 ≈ 10 * (5/375 + 1)^(1/5), then 752/375 + 754/376 + 756/377 + 758/378 + 760/379 + 762/380 ≈ 12 * (6/375 + 1)^(1/6), then 752/375 + 754/376 + 756/377 + 758/378 + 760/379 + 762/380 + 764/381 ≈ 14 * (7/375 + 1)^(1/7)</sub>

Comment: Please, when you ask [mathematics] questions, use the broad tag as well as any specific sub-field tag. Also, what is the question here exactly? Do you want a mathematical justification for the "almost equalities"? In the form of an equation/proof?

Comment: Any justification will do.

Comment: Please don't use `*` in MathJax to represent multiplication. Use `\times` instead.

Comment: Should solvers be concerned with the way you don't define 'almost'?

Comment: @ cotton, you should not  be concerned.

Comment: Where did this question come from? Did you create it? If not, please add source.

Comment: @ user 71981. All the questions I put on this site  our  my own creations in addition to that most derive from my unpublished mathematical work. Today I will post more mysterious fractions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They can be justified by viewing the left and right sides of each (approximate) equality as

> the arithmetic mean and the geometric mean of some very close numbers, respectively.

To see this, let's focus on the first line and transform it a bit.

> Divide both sides by 2:
>
> $$ \frac{376}{375} + \frac{377}{376} + \frac{378}{377} + \frac{379}{378} + \frac{380}{379} \approx 5 \times \left(\frac{380}{375}\right)^{1/5} $$

> and then by the number of terms on the left side:
>
> $$ \frac{\frac{376}{375} + \frac{377}{376} + \frac{378}{377} + \frac{379}{378} + \frac{380}{379}}{5} \approx \left(\frac{380}{375}\right)^{1/5} $$

> Since
>
> $$ \frac{376}{375} \times \frac{377}{376} \times \frac{378}{377} \times \frac{379}{378} \times \frac{380}{379} = \frac{380}{375} $$
>
> it follows that the left side is the arithmetic mean of the five fractions, and the right side is their geometric mean. The other two lines can be justified in the similar fashion.